# Issue with loading time and date in DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, sql, windows, linq, datetimepicker

I have columns named *Time* and *date* where I am storing values using `DateTimePicker` like this:

```
Time = 14:38:00
Date = 11/11/2015
```

And I set the properties as follows:

```
DateTimePicker.Format = Time
DateTimePicker.Format= Date
```

Now I am getting a problem binding both values in *DateTimePicker*.

I am selecting values from a database using LNQ query like this:

```
public static void BindControls(DateTimePicker ArrivalTime, DateTimePicker ArrivalDate)
{
    TNTDATADataContext Context = new TNTDATADataContext();
    var q = (from v in Context.Customers
             where v.Code == Code.Text
             select new {vv.ArrivalTime,v.ArrivalDate }).First();

    ArrivalTime.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(q.ArrivalTime);
    ArrivalDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(q.ArrivalDate);
}
```

The exception that I am getting is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

```
ArrivalTime.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(q.ArrivalTime);
ArrivalDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(q.ArrivalDate);
```

I want to bind these values in DateTimePicker from a saved Time and Date.

Comment: ArrivalTime contains only time and ArrivalDate is also contains only date in backhand

Comment: why are you storing date and time in two timespans? you can store it in one `DateTime` structure.

Comment: I'm storing is like that because it was need to store like that as per requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `ArrivalTime` is a `TimeSpan`. You could simply use `DateTime.Today` as date-portion:

```
ArrivalTime.Value = DateTime.Today + q.ArrivalTime;
ArrivalDate.Value = q.ArrivalDate;
```

Comment: @developer: you're welcome. Maybe it is even better to use `q.ArrivalDate + q.ArrivalTime`. But that depends on your business logic which i don't know.

Comment: yes its is better to use and working perfectly like i want